# After MAKE how to run an excutable file

Tags: c++, makefile

I am testing a .cpp file 'DisplayImage.cpp' using `cmake` and `make`.
After the command `cmake`, it shows

> -- Configuring done 
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: /media/administrator/000F47E10007C546/exCV

then I use the command make and I get an excutable file DisplayImage like this:

> [100%] Built target DisplayImage

but the problem is that I can't run this excutable file an it shows:

> administrator@ubuntu:/media/administrator/000F47E10007C546/exCV$ DisplayImage
>   DisplayImage：未找到命令(which mean cannot find the command)

Can anyone help me fix this problem ? Thanks a lot!
Acctually I am following the tutotial:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

Answer (score 1):

You're probably launching your program wrongly. You should have written `./DisplayImage`, not just `DisplayImage`

In your case it'd look like this:

```
administrator@ubuntu:/media/administrator/000F47E10007C546/exCV$ ./DisplayImage
```

---

EDIT regarding your comments:

If you're told that you don't have permission to execute this file (which is pretty odd as the compiler should've done everything so your program could be run), you should just give yourself this permission:

```
sudo chmod +x DisplayImage
```

---

When you write `ProgramName`, the OS is trying to search for this `ProgramName` in the directories listed in your `PATH` variable. So if you write `DisplayImage`, this search certainly won't succeed, that's why you're getting an error message.

But if you do `./DisplayImage`, the system will search for an executable with such a name in your *current directory*. You also could have written `/path/to/your/executable/DisplayImage`.

Comment: >administrator@ubuntu:/media/administrator/000F47E10007C546/exCV$ ./DisplayImage
bash: ./DisplayImage: 权限不够 (which means the permission is not enough)

Comment: and I tried also : <br>administrator@ubuntu:/media/administrator/000F47E10007C546/exCV$ sudo ./DisplayImage
[sudo] password for administrator: 
sudo：./DisplayImage: command not found

Comment: @LouiseGAN What does `ls -l DisplayImage` say?

Comment: @LouiseGAN, this means that you actually have this file but you can't execute it. Please check the edits to my answer.

Comment: @EtanReisner it shows no such file or directory but that's odd because I can see it by using ls

Comment: Show us the `ls` output? Try `ls -l Di<tab>` to tab complete it instead (in case there is anything funny about the name)?

Comment: @LouiseGAN, so if you can see this file with `ls`, why can't you see it with `ls -l`? So if your build succeeds, that means this file _is_ there.

Comment: It shows like this: administrator@ubuntu:/media/administrator/000F47E10007C546/exCV$ ls
agnes.jpg       CMakeFiles           CMakeLists.txt  DisplayImage.cpp
CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  DisplayImage    Makefile

Comment: @LouiseGAN, cool, this file _is there_. Now try to make it executable (`sudo chmod +x DisplayImage`)

Comment: I mean it shows something after ls -l  and it's like administrator@ubuntu:/media/administrator/000F47E10007C546/exCV$ ls -l DisplayImage
-rw------- 1 administrator administrator 18999 11月 24 20:56 DisplayImage

Comment: Notice that no x bit is set, they would show up there, so execute that `chmod` command ForceBru mentioned and try again.